# Flutter: Is it posible to run function from state in other script

Tags: android, function, class, flutter, dart

So my question is: Is it posible to run function from state in other script?

E.g: 
I have 2 scripts, lets say i have main.dart and loadingScreen.dart

**main.dart**

```
//...
OutlineButton(
   child: Text("Status", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17), textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
   borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[400]),
   onPressed: () async {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/loadingScreen', arguments: {"text": "Checking\nstatus"});
      //...
      // <--- Here I want to run updateLoadingText from loadingScreen.dart
      Navigator.pop(context);
   }
),
//...
```

**loadingScreen.dart**

```
class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  Map data = {};
  String loadingText;

  updateLoadingText(newText){
    //...
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //...
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async => false,
        child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              SpinKitCubeGrid(
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 80,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 24,),
              Text(
                loadingText,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 35,                
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is it possible to run updateLoadingText in main.dart?

Thx for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by passing a key to the widget and then using the key to access the widget's state. (You will need to make the state class public to do this.)

**main.dart**

```dart
// In the class fields
final loadingScreenKey = GlobalKey<LoadingScreenState>();

// Where you build LoadingScreen
LoadingScreen(
  key: loadingScreenKey,
  // ...
),

// Button code
OutlineButton(
   // ...
   onPressed: () async {
      // ...
      loadingScreenKey.currentState.updateLoadingText(...),
   },
),
```

### **DISCLAIMER**

Calling a state method from another widget directly like this is generally considered bad form since this will produce highly coupled and decentralized spaghetti code. As such, you should instead look into a system where you notify the widget to change via an impartial service. There are a lot of ways to do this, such as with an event bus, a `ChangeNotifier`, or with a state management library like provider or flutter_bloc.